# How to implement load on demand by simple JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web, scroll, infinite

I have one screen in my web application will load many records and take long time.  Is there anyway I can  implement Ajax "load on demand" - only load small group records - by simple JavaScript?

Any suggestion is great appreciated.

Comment: Yes of course there is. Search the Web and Stackoverflow for "*pagination*", "*infinite scroll*" or similar. Some table viewer widgets have support for loading only the data set that is viewed. And you can always "stream" your records in small groups so that the first are shown already while the other ones are still loaded. However, the more performant you need that, the less simple it will get.

Comment: Thanks Cole Johnson,  "infinite scroll" is what I am looking for.